# how to turn stack in to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I am working on a stack, where i have to create it from scratch without using JAVA collections. I have coded the push, pop, peek and all other required methods. What I am confused about is the method of converting this stack to an array, with the top of the stack being element 0, how can this be done without using the toArray() method?

Comment: Just create an array with the same size as the stack, iterate through elements and assign them to their respective index.

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have a `Stack<Double>`:

```
public static Double[] stackToArray(Stack<Double> s){

     Double[] arr = new Double[s.size()];

     for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
          arr[i] = s.top();
          s.pop();
     }
     return arr;
}
```

I did this on my cell phone, so sorry about the formatting.